Embeddings of symplectic singularities into smooth manifolds
Let $X$ be a symplectic variety with terminal singularities of dimension $2n$, $\sigma\in H^0(X^{reg},\Omega^2_{X^{reg}})$ a holomorphic symplectic form. Pick a neighborhood $U$ of a point $x\in X$.

Can we find a smooth symplectic manifold $U'$ with a holomorphic symplectic form $\sigma'$ such that $U$ embeds into $U'$ as a closed subvariety and the restriction of $\sigma'$ to $U$ coincides with $\sigma$?

And now suppose that $X$ admits a Lagrangian fibration $\pi\colon X\to B$ to a smooth manifold $B$. Let $U$ be a neighborhood of $x\in X$ and $V$ a neighborhood of $\pi(x)\in B$.

Can we find a smooth symplectic manifold $(U',\sigma')$ as above together with a Lagrangian fibration $\pi'\colon U'\to V'\times W$ for some smooth $W$ such that the following diagram commutes?

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    (U,\sigma) @>>> (U',\sigma') \\
    @V{\pi}VV @V{\pi'}VV \\
    V @>>> V\times W
\end{CD}

No that is not true.  If it were true then the two form would extend to a global section of the second exterior power of the sheaf of regular differentials on $X$.  But often the two form does not extend, e.g., isolated ADE surface singularities.

@JasonStarr What if $X$ has terminal singularities? Does the form extend to to a global form in this case?

Let $X'$ be a smooth, projective, hyperKaehler manifold with dimension $2n$ that contains a smooth subvariety $P$ that is abstractly isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^n$.  Since the restriction of every holomorphic $2$-form to $P$ is identically zero, the normal bundle of $P$ in $X'$ is necessarily isomorphic to the cotangent bundle of $P$, which is antiample, and the extension of the normal bundle by the tangent bundle is split.  By Artin's formal contraction theorem (or maybe something simpler), there is a contraction $X'\to X$ mapping $P$ to a point.  For $n>1$, $X$ is crepant.

@JasonStarr Are you saying that the $2$-form on $X^\reg$ as in your comment cannot extend to a global form on $X$?

Yes, that is what I claimed, but now I need to think whether it is true.  I will check in the case that $X’$ is the Hilbert scheme of length-$n$ closed subschemes of a K3 surface containing a smooth $(-2)$ curve.  That should settle it.
